# How do I find an image similar to the input image from a directory?

Tags: python, opencv, image-recognition

I have a python program which will detect images from webcam. Now, I want to compare the image recognized by the webcam with the images in my directory and check if the exact similar image is already existing or not.

I have tried using [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/12/01/complete-guide-building-image-search-engine-python-opencv/) recognition algorithm but it does not work. The program always outputs single image no matter how different the input image is.

The input image(the image scanned by the webcam) is little blurry [like this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqB08xj3dOgrgoZdutlrHV4n6qylvg) while the image in the data set [looks like this](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqB08xj3dOgrgoZeSzIR2Zc3eYHY4g)

I need an algorithm which can recognize these images with more accuracy.

Comment: I recommend you use K-nearest-neighbors method, `from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier`, sklearn already have that model. Just remember to resize the image in directory to be same shape with query image

Comment: I'm new to machine learning. Can you send me a reference where I can learn more about the K-nearest-neighbors ?

Comment: it completely depends on how you define "similar" and this is in general a very hard task, so don't expect to get a satisfying answer which really works for your task. If you can limit the possible distortions (e.g. "only blurred and some compression artifacts") it becomes better answerable

Comment: Thank you. The KNN algorithm is working perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i write a small script for you, hope that it could solve your problem

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

def read_img_from_dir(directory, query_shape):
    # query_shape is a tuple which contain the size (width, height) of query image
    # directory is your dir contain image you wanna find
    name_image = []
    shape = query
    first = True
    for pics in os.listdir(directory):
        name_image.append(pics)
        image = Image.open(pics)
        image = image.resize(shape)
        image = np.array(image)
        image = np.reshape(image,(1,-1))
        if first:
            img_array = np.copy(image)
            first = False
        else:
            img_array = np.concatenate((img,array,image),axis=0)
    return name_image, img_array    

def find_by_knn(img, list_name, list_array):
    # image_query is path of your picture you wanna find
    # list_name and list_array is result of above function
    img = np.reshape(img,(1,-1))
    num_pics = list_array.shape[0]
    dists = np.zeros((num_pics,1))
    dists = list(np.sqrt(np.sum((list_array-img)**2,axis = 1)))
    idx = dists.index(max(dists))
    return list_name[idx]

img = cv2.imread(image_query)
shape = img.shape[:2]
name_image, img_array = read_img_from_dir(directory,shape)
result = find_by_knn(img, name_image, img_array)
print(result)
```

If you wanna know more about KNN, take a look at this link: http://cs231n.github.io/classification/#nn

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have used KNN algorithm its working perfect. I have not used the code you have mentioned as it was showing few errors. but that resource that you mentioned has really helped me.

Answer (score -1):

## IMAGE SEARCH by using python openCV.

## LINK FOR open CV

opencv_python‑4.1.0+contrib‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

## download the import cv2

```
import numpy as np
```

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

pip install numpy

pip install matplotlib

## Matplotlib is used for displaying frames from video or images.

Numpy is used for all things "numbers and Python." 
We are mainly making use of Numpy's array functionality.

```
   import cv2
```

import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Firstly we are going to import few things
Next, we define img to be cv2.read(image file, parms).

The default is going to be IMREAD_COLOR, which is color without any alpha channel.

For the second parameter, you can use -1, 0, or 1. Color is 1, gray scale is 0, and the unchanged is -1. Thus, for gray scale, one could do img = cv2.imread('watch.jpg', 0)

Once loaded, we use cv2.imshow(title,image) to show the image. From here,
 we use the `cv2.waitKey(0)` to wait until any key is pressed. Once that's done, 
we use `cv2.destroyAllWindows()` to close everything.

Loading Video Source Open CV Python 
with video and webcams.

handling frames from a video is identical to handling for images.

code--

```
 import numpy as np

import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

 while(True):

ret, frame = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):

    break

cap.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

we import numpy and cv2  Next, we cay cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0).

```
  while(True):
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

we have ret and frame being defined as the cap.read().

```
  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

*we define a new variable, gray, as the frame, converted to gray.

## note**

*OpenCV reads colors as BGR (Blue Green Red), 
where most computer applications read as RGB (Red Green Blue).

```
 cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
```

## Here, we're showing the converted-to-gray feed.

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
  break
```

## if key is a q, we will exit the while loop with a break, which then runs:

```
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This releases the webcam, then closes all of the imshow() windows.

## if you want to save the recording and then process it by using,

```
 import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)


fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))


while(True):

ret, frame = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
out.write(frame)
cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: then try reverse_image_search,