How to find similar images for given image in a directory
I am new to machine learning and Python, I am trying to find the best-matched (similar) images in a directory for the given image.
For example, I have 50.000 coin images in a folder and trying to find the top 10 best-matching images with the user-specified image.
Here are my sample files https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pxz4nuyWfSLcrzs0QZpvqWO77ZI3Vn6M?usp=sharing
Here is the sample search image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cWTxLIjG2pKW4-1g-LYfdAbccG18sPnX/view?usp=sharing
I also modified the given image with OpenCV but nothing changed here is the cropped version https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AvZbPgZJvPwSBqNxVZ9N7t-DxTI_Xzsl/view?usp=sharing
The expectation is that 18206-f.jpg should be the best-matched file according to the specified sample file.
I tried many algorithms and provided solutions like the one below, but I could not find a proper solution.

I used a custom training model with image classification as mentioned here https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification but I failed I am guessing that I don't have a different file for the specific sample, I also tried a custom data augmentation mechanism but failed again (failed = could not find the right-related- files)

I used https://github.com/TechyNilesh/DeepImageSearch but failed I guess this kind of solution is best for semantic searches, I need image-to-image search like image similarity, not keyword/content similarity, etc.

I used hashing algorithms like Ahash, Dhash, and Phash but failed when the image was in different conditions, etc.

I tried the KNN search mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56881718/6799182 but it failed again.


How can I find the best matching image from the specified one. In my example dataset.
Input: 1-tl.jpg
Output:
1853-f.jpg
...
...
...
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np

from typing import Union

def read_img_from_dir(image_dir: str, query_shape: Union[list, tuple]) -> tuple[list, np.ndarray]:
    name_image = []
    img_array = np.empty((0, np.prod(query_shape)), dtype=np.float32)
    for image_name in os.listdir(image_dir):
        name_image.append(image_name)
        image = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_dir, image_name))
        if not isinstance(image, np.ndarray):
            # if path is not image
            continue
        image = cv2.resize(image, query_shape[:2][::-1])
        image = image.reshape(1, -1) / 255.
        img_array = np.concatenate((img_array, image))
    return name_image, img_array    

def find_by_knn(query_img: np.ndarray, list_name: list[str], database: np.ndarray) -> str:
    query_img = query_img.reshape(1, -1) / 255.
    dists = np.sqrt(np.sum((database-query_img) ** 2,axis = 1))
    idx = dists.argmin()
    return list_name[idx]

if __name__=='__main__':
    image_query = '1tl-cropped.png'
    image_dir = 'sample_flat'
    img = cv2.imread(image_query)
    
    # optional: since the query image size maybe large, resize 
    # all image to a small disired shape may avoid OOM problem
    # and boost computing speed
    
    # global_shape = (320, 320)
    # img = cv2.resize(img, global_shape)
    
    shape = img.shape
    name_image, img_array = read_img_from_dir(image_dir, shape)
    result = find_by_knn(img, name_image, img_array)
    print(result)


First: be sure that all relevant detail is in your question, not as links to external storage areas (once those disappear, the question is effectively broken). Aside from that: you're asking for a recommendation, which is off-topic.

I did add, a minimal set of your external files, to this question. I added them at the end of the question to still make your question readable.   I kept the links for the curious people who do want to see more images.... (as long as they are shared on that location....)

I am not an expert in image comparison, but I do note that the background is different, which might make unneeded comparing hard.....

Did you try feature matching using SIFT and filtering the matches and getting a match score or warping the test images to match the template image, then doing some kind of template matching?  Did you try doing the same but then doing edge detection such as Canny before doing the template matching?

@Luuk Yes I tried with the background removed images but could not find the right solution.  Here is the cropper png version of my little dataset https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HghIHovhZlzRejlFQQLVEHqtv7eeLzrO?usp=sharing if somebody wants to try a solution, it might be helpful.

@fmw42 As far as I can see the SIFT is deprecated and we have the newer version called ORB. I tried with ORB like mentioned here https://youtu.be/16s3Pi1InPU but this is not a solution, unfortunately.
Here is the code https://github.com/bnsreenu/python_for_microscopists/blob/master/191_measure_img_similarity.py

I stopped looking at your problem after replacing 1tl-cropped.png by 18205-f.jpg, and seeing that it could find itself as perfect match....

SIFT is not deprecated. it used to be patented, but that expired many years ago. ORB isn't a newer version, it's an attempt to reengineer something similar without violating the patent.
